# Xpath expression for a piece of html

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

```
<div id="260726c74b52e9204ce9a8ec9a-buttons" class="button-container">
    <button data-pid="RM110126998" class="add-to-cart-hover btn btn-block btn-primary typo-uppercase add-to-cart-event-ready" data-available-text="Add to cart" data-preorder="false" data-findinstore="false">Add to cart</button>
</div>
```

I want an xpath to be able to click on the button.

The '260726c74b52e9204ce9a8ec9a' value is the product id and is picked at random and stored in Elementid.

I have tried this - `By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), '"+Elementid+"')]-buttons/button"` and it returns an error.

When I get the xpath for the element on Firepath I get this - id('59d907c3c3204a630df88782a7-buttons')/x:button

How can I modify this xpath to use the string contained in Elementid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By.xpath("//div[@id='" + Elementid + "-buttons']/button") should do it

Comment: Code only answers are not allowed on SO. Please take a minute to explain what the code does and why it answers the question.